# Error to generate apk through buildozer android debugger in terminal

Tags: android, kivy, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, buildozer

I am stuck on this issue it takes a long time, I am following a tutorial video explaining how to install Kivy, Buildozer and compile apk file. Until now, I have installed the supposed dependencies:

```
victor@victor-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev
```

```
victor@victor-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install libltdl-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev autoconf autotools-dev
```

explained at the video, after installed buildozer, I went on my project's folder, opened the terminal there and performed:

```
victor@victor-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test$ buildozer init
```

And at my project folder to create the spec file:

```
victor@victor-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test$ buildozer android debug
```

And my error log gave the following stderr:

```
.... .....
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> run...(and 62 more)
Exception in thread background thread for pid 18490:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/ndk-build V=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a

  STDOUT:
Android NDK: : Cannot find module with tag 'cxx-stl/system' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
/home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:126: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1196, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 671, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 155, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 209, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 580, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in build_arch
    super(Sqlite3Recipe, self).build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 816, in build_arch
    *extra_args, _env=env
  File "/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/ndk-build V=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a

  STDOUT:
Android NDK: : Cannot find module with tag 'cxx-stl/system' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
/home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:126: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/victor/Desktop/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     HOME = '/home/victor'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'appmenu-qt5'
#     LC_TIME = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/victor/Desktop'
#     GTK2_MODULES = 'overlay-scrollbar'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     UNITY_HAS_3D_SUPPORT = 'true'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     USER = 'victor'
#     LC_NAME = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     LC_PAPER = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/victor/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     SESSIONTYPE = 'gnome-session'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_PID = ''
#     UPSTART_JOB = 'unity7'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/victor-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1707,unix/victor-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1707'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     UPSTART_SESSION = 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1398'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL = ''
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module'
#     PATH = '/home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/victor/bin:/home/victor/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     VTE_VERSION = '4205'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     JOB = 'unity-settings-daemon'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_CTYPE = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/victor'
#     QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON = '1'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-VN8CdmaJHr'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     UNITY_DEFAULT_PROFILE = 'unity'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/victor/.Xauthority'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     COMPIZ_BIN_PATH = '/usr/bin/'
#     PWD = '/home/victor/Desktop/Test'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     UPSTART_EVENTS = 'xsession started'
#     WINDOWID = '73400330'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     LOGNAME = 'victor'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     UPSTART_INSTANCE = ''
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/home/victor/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/victor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

For it I only got the lack of the 'cxx-stl/system' in import path before the exception display but I don't have idea about how to deal with it and fix, I would like to know if there are dependencies missing or something?

Comment: Never seen this before, not clear what's wrong.

Comment: This error sounded so weird to me also, i am trying now to perform this kivy and buildozer installing in another VM to see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Actually command

```
buildozer init
```

creates .spec file. So you should create it, write down everything you need, and after that you can run

```
buildozer android debug
```

Also you have some problems with defining path to NDK, so you can try download NDK by yourself, unzip it to some folder and write path to it in the .spec file.